# Why can implicit read not find my object type scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework, implicit

Trying to write an implicit read after I wrote an implicit write to read my custom type back into scala values

`

```
implicit val locationReads: Reads[Equipment] = (
      (JsPath \ "numberOwned").read[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "name").read[String]
      )(Equipment.apply _)
```

`

My custom type "Equipment" has variables numberOwned and name", when writing this the error that shows up is "Cannot resolve symbol Equipment".

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Did you import `Equipment` type into the scope of above implicit?

Comment: yes I did, passing in type Equipment into Reads[] did not give me any error so I'm not sure why the last part did

Comment: Could you share compiler error as-is, what you have got in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and let me know if it helps.

```
  import play.api.libs.json._
  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

  case class Equipment(numberOwned: Int, name: String)

  implicit def equipmentReads: Reads[Equipment] = {
    try {
      JsSuccess(Equipment(
        (v \ "numberOwned").as[Int],
        (v \ "name").as[String]
      ))
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => Reads {
        case _ =>
          JsError(JsonValidationError("Cannot De-serialize Equipment value."))
      }
    }
  }
```